# Fetch data from extrenal excel file thorugh Jquery without using mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have an external excel file "my_rate.xls" having rows "Sl_no", "Item_code",'Item-desc", "unit", "Item_rate".  Now I want to put an HTML interactive form  with connecting the external excel file with PHP.  so that any body click the item of the HTML form, will know the rate.

kindly help in furnishing the Source code to fetch the required data of excel sheet through the PHP form. Any jquery / JSOnN script also  ( but I not MYSQL)

Comment: You will need to read the Excel file with PHP somehow. I'd start there. Since you're asking use to code up an entire solution for you, I won't offer you more help than assisting you with research, as that's your job.

Comment: also, you should tag this one php, not javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can read excel files via odbc, as if they were a database: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch15_04.htm

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php

Google has many other hits on how to do this. There may be platform specific issues with the required drivers, though...